# Null values loaded into Cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, plsql, cursor

So I created a couple of cursor to store the data that is being loaded into a table. The data is being loaded one at a time and I need to do validations on the entire set of data and not just the individual record.So there would be data like this (but again it would only be loaded individual and not as a whole)

```
form_no  |  type
---------------
5155-55  |  -1
5155-55  |  -1
5155-55  |   2
5155-55  |   1
         |
4568-98  |  -1
4568-98  |  -1
4568-98  |  -1
4568-98  |   2
4568-98  |   1   

3302-48  |  1
3302-45  |  2 
3302-45  | -1
```

So then the cursors are taking the sum or each type and then pairing it with a distinct form_no. Then at the bottom it is checking to make sure that there is always a 1 and -1 with each form_no (i.e. form_no 5155-55 has at least one type 1 and one type -1)

```
DECLARE
 error VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';

CURSOR XXX IS
SELECT form_no, sum(type) as sum_type_neg
  FROM my_table
 WHERE type = -1
 GROUP BY form_no;

CURSOR YYY IS
SELECT form_no, sum(type) as sum_type_pos
  FROM my_table
 WHERE type = 1
 GROUP BY form_no;

CURSOR ZZZ(xx_form_no VARCHAR2, yy_form_no VARCHAR2) IS
SELECT form_no
  FROM my_table
 WHERE form_no = xx_form_no
   AND form_no = vv_form_no
 GROUP BY form_no;

x_form  XXX%ROWTYPE;
y_form  YYY%ROWTYPE;
ZZZRow  ZZZ%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
OPEN XXX;
LOOP
  FETCH XXX
    INTO x_form;
  EXIT WHEN XXX%NOTFOUND;

  OPEN YYY;
  LOOP
    FETCH YYY
      INTO y_form;
    EXIT WHEN YYY%NOTFOUND;

    OPEN ZZZ(x_form.form_no, y_form.form_no);
    LOOP
      FETCH ZZZ
        INTO ZZZRow;
      EXIT WHEN ZZZ%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line('Distinct: ' || x_form.form_no);
      dbms_output.put_line('SUM x:    ' || x_form.sum_type_neg);
      dbms_output.put_line('SUM y:    ' || y_form.sum_type_pos);
      dbms_output.put_line('----------------------------');
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ZZZ;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE YYY;
END LOOP;
CLOSE XXX;

IF x_form.sum_type_neg = O or y_form.sum_type_pos = 0 THEN
  v_error_in_process := 'Y';
  dbms_output.put_line('ERROR MESSAGE');
ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('GREATE JOB');
END IF;

END;
```

Output would be like this

```
 Distinct : 5155-55
 SUM x:    -2
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 Distinct: 4568-98
 SUM x:    -3
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 Distinct: 3302-48
 SUM x:    -1
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 GREAT JOB!
```

It works great except when the form_no does not have a -1 or 1 

Example input:

```
form_no  |  type
---------------
5155-55  |  -1
5155-55  |  -1
5155-55  |   2
5155-55  |   1
         |
4568-98  |  -1
4568-98  |  -1
4568-98  |  -1
4568-98  |   2
4568-98  |   1 

3302-48  |   1
3302-48  |   2
```

Notice that form_no 3302-48 doesn't have a -1. So then the output would be like this

```
 Distinct: 5155-55
 SUM x:    -2
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 Distinct: 4568-98
 SUM x:    -3
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 GREAT JOB!
```

EXCEPT I want it to be like this

```
 Distinct: 5155-55
 SUM x:    -2
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 Distinct: 4568-98
 SUM x:    -3
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 Distinct: 3302-48
 SUM x:     0
 SUM y:     1
 ----------------------------
 ERROR MESSAGE
```

Could anyone tell me how to go about doing this. I am not sure if a cursor can take in null values (i.e. when there is no 1 or -1 then there would be nothing to load into the cursor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no need of PL/SQL processing involvement, you can achieve the desired result using just SQL:

```
SQL> select col
  2       , val
  3    from ( select form_no as "Distinct:"
  4                , to_char(sum(case when type1 = -1 then type1 else 0 end)) as sumx
  5                , to_char(sum(case when type1 = 1  then type1 else 0 end)) as sumy
  6            from t1
  7           group by form_no
  8         )
  9  unpivot(
 10     val for col in ("Distinct:", sumx, sumy)
 11   )
 12  ;
```

Result:

```
COL       VAL
--------- ----------
Distinct: 5155-55
SUMX      -2
SUMY      1

Distinct: 4568-98
SUMX      -3
SUMY      1

Distinct: 3302-48
SUMX      0
SUMY      1

9 rows selected
```

Note. `Unpivot` operator has been introduced in Oracle 11g version and is used in the above query just for data formatting. if your Oracle version is prior to 11g, you can just take a sub-query(in-line view) and format output as you wish using PL/SQL.

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cc23a/1)